# Why does adding a simple boolean as a socket.emit parameter cause "Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

App.js in my react frontend contains:

```
const validateRoom = () => { // called by a child, this function is passed to it
    socket.emit("check_for_room", roomCode);
  }

const joinRoom = (roomIndex=-1) => {
    if (TRUE) {
      socket.emit("set_username", username);
      socket.emit("set_roomCode", roomCode);
      socket.emit("set_isHost", isHost);
      socket.emit("set_capacity", capacity);
      socket.emit("join_room", roomIndex);
    }
  };

  socket.on("room_with_code", (room) => { // returns bool
    setValidRoom(room.exists);
    if (room.exists) {
      joinRoom(room.index);
    }
  });
```

my server's index.js with socket.io contains:

```
socket.on("check_for_room", (roomCode) => {
    const index = waitingLobbies.findIndex(e => e.roomCode === roomCode);
    if (index > -1) {
      // waitingLobbies contains roomCode at index
      socket.emit("room_with_code", {exists: true, index: index});
    } else {
      socket.emit("room_with_code", {exists: false, index: index});
    }
  });
socket.on("join_room", (roomIndex) => {
   ... stuff that doesn't even use roomIndex
}
```

I truly don't believe any of the other code matters because even if I remove everything from the socket.on "join_room" listen, my code crashes with the "Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError" error. But if I just change my emit from client, and take out the parameter roomIndex, everything works fine! Why does adding one single boolean to the parameters change anything at all?

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors usually mean that you are trying to emit some data that contains circular references (the error is thrown when calling `JSON.stringify()` on the arguments).

Could you please check?